# Thousands of SELECT statements w/ LIKE searches on large text fields -- how to improve performance?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I making a plugin in wordpress, that looks at all files to see if the file is use.
The problem is that when I get all files and make a query of each one of them, there will be lots of queries.

For example 3000 sql statements like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " . $table_prefix . "posts  
WHERE post_content LIKE '%/$fileName%';
```

And the real problem is if a make lots of sql query the server will go down, so the question is how can I query for 3000 files without compromising the server.

For example i make a scan in one dir and i found

a.jpg
b.jpg
c.jpg
d.jpg
......
......
z.jpg

so the only way to know if each one of them is use the query i wrote before, so i will have some like this

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " . $table_prefix . "posts  
    WHERE post_content LIKE 'a.jpg';
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " . $table_prefix . "posts  
    WHERE post_content LIKE 'b.jpg';
....
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " . $table_prefix . "posts  
        WHERE post_content LIKE 'z.jpg';
```

and i use this query because i'm searching if the file is refered in any post, if the count is 0 that means the file is not used

So for the people who ask what is the question, is how i can make all that query without problem or how i can change the query for better search of each file

Comment: How is the performance on that query?  It looks like it could be expensive...

Comment: I get your scenario, but what's the question, specifically?

Comment: Looks like you want to use full-text search: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: @AbeMiessler is very expensive, but is the only way i found to search if the file is in any post

Comment: @adrian i update for explain a little more

Answer (score 0):

You should store a reference to a file (1:1 or 1:N) in another table. Then you don't have to use the 'like'-Statement and the performance should be much better. then you also can handle all with only one sql-statment:

```
select count(*), file_id from ... group by file_id
```

If you don't want to change your db model, you could try something like this:

```
select count(*), files.filename from 
POSTS p left join ((select 'a.jpg' as filename) union (select 'b.jpg' as filename) union ...) files
on p.post_content CONCAT('%', files.filename, '%') collate utf8_general_ci
group by files.filename
```

Comment: yes, you have rigth , but the problem is i dont whant change how wordpress manage the file

Comment: I have added a way without changing the db model, but I don't know how fast it is.